# why I can not run npm run dev successfully?

Tags: laravel, npm

> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

/Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:93
                throw err;
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'js' of undefined
    at Object. (/Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/webpack.mix.js:16:3)
    at Module._compile (/Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (/Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object. (/Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:12:1)
    at Module._compile (/Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (/Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:116:13)
    at requireConfig (/Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:118:6)
    at /Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:125:17
    at Array.forEach ()
    at module.exports (/Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:123:15)
    at yargs.parse (/Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:71:45)
    at Object.parse (/Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:567:18)
    at /Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:49:8
    at Object. (/Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:390:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object. (/Users/xwu33/src/bioproc/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:156:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/xwu33/.npm/_logs/2019-06-21T17_03_18_125Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/xwu33/.npm/_logs/2019-06-21T17_03_18_244Z-debug.log

Comment: Is this on a fresh Laravel install, or have you added a bunch of changes to it? What's your node version?

Comment: node version is v10.15.2

Comment: I have added a brunch of changes to this project, fresh laravel project works fine. I tried to delete package-lock.json file and run: npm install then npm run dev, but it is the same error.

Comment: If a fresh Laravel works fine, and this one doesn't, that would seem to indicate your code/modifications are at fault. Given that you haven't shared them, this is hard to assist you with.

Comment: When I created a fresh laravel project. It is the same npm run dev error though.

Comment: I removed node_modules file and run npm install, fresh laravel works fine now. I need to check my modifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I changed `webpack.mix.js` file like this:

// TypeError: Cannot read property 'js' of undefined

`const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');`

// work

`const mix = require('laravel-mix');`

Then it works for me!

Answer (score 2):

Removed `node_modules`, then `npm install --global cross-env`, followed by removing `cross-env` from `package.json`, then `npm run dev` worked.

Comment: I find it is about js problem, when I uodate vue like: npm update vue and install sass. Then it works fine.